# How can I access values in another class inherited from public class C#?

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, public

I get an error when inheriting from public class I can't access values of another class.

AppEngine.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestEngine
{
    public class AppEngine : Appstrings
    {
        public async Task<string> Testing()
        {
            return wrongUserName;
        }
    }
}
```

Appstrings.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestEngine
{
    public class Appstrings
    {
        string wrongUserName = "Wrong username. Please check and try again..";
    }
}
```

I want to access the values that I defined in the Appstrings class by inheriting them from the AppEngine class. This is the code I wrote, but the error I get is `'Appstrings.wrongUserName' is inaccessible due to its protection level.` It is said that it cannot be inherited due to protection, but the class construction is public. Where do you think I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on [C# language reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/basic-concepts#745-class-members)

> Class members can have any of the five kinds of declared accessibility and default to private declared accessibility.

So, the `wrongUserName` has the `private` accessibility inside the `Appstrings` class. You must specify the accessibility of the member explicitly to `internal`, `protected`, or `public` (not recommended).

```cs
namespace TestEngine
{
    public class Appstrings
    {
        protected string wrongUserName = "Wrong username. Please check and try again..";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Access modifiers also apply to properties. If you don't set one it's implicitely set to `private`. So if you want to set it to `public` you'll need to add it infront of the property, although `protected` would also work if you only want to make it accessable by inheritance:

```cs
public string wrongUsername = "...";
```

See [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers#summary-table) for the complete list of access modifiers.